# alert dynamic array javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have tried to google this through for the past 3 days.

I have a script running that generates lines randomly on a google api map. I have added an event listener to alert a value depending on which line is clicked. Currently the alert is only popping up the last value in the array due to the key being used.

```
function setLines(json) {
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.lines.length; i++) {
        var line = data.lines[i];
        var loc1 = line.Location1;
        var loc2 = line.Location2;
        var name = line.name;
        comment[name] = {"comment":line.Comment};
        var endpoints = [myObject[loc1], myObject[loc2]];
        createline[name] = new google.maps.Polyline({path:endpoints, strokeColor: line.Color, strokeWeight: line.Weight, zIndex: line.ZIndex, map: map });
        google.maps.event.addListener(createline[name], 'click', function() {alert(comment[name]); });        
        lines.push(createline[name]);
    }
}
```

How can I get the actual value of comment[name] to populate into the alert during generation so that it is not called when clicked instead?

Comment: What does your `json` look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including sample data.  I suspect that this.name will contain the data you need in the `click` listener (or you can add that property to the polyline so it does).

Comment: Here is a working example page: http;//humorlessjester.net/Xera/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event handlers uses the variable `name`, but each event handler doesn't have its own variable, they all share the same. At the time the event handler is called, the variable has changes to its final value.

You can use a function wrapper to create a copy of the variable for each iteration in the loop:

```
(function(name){
  google.maps.event.addListener(createline[name], 'click', function() {alert(comment[name]); });
})(name);
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I have been struggling with how to get it get that export in each loop. This worked perfectly.